# Using another plugin Class on a mu-plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm willing to use an ACF Class on my mu-plugin, but as it is loaded before the normal plugins I can not call the class, any ideas on how should I proceed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to wrap it in this hook - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/